# How to convert a YouTube video URL to the iframe embed code dynamically on page load?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, spring-mvc

I'm using this to convert youtube url to embed url. I am new in jquery please advice me in code.

```
function vidgallerylist()
{
     var url=path+"/customer/video";


            var value = $(this).attr(result.data[i].vidgalleryUrl);
            value = value.replace('feature=player_embedded&','');
            if (value.match('(http(s)?://)?(www.)?youtube|youtu\.be')) 
            {
                if (value.match('embed')) { youtube_id = value.split(/embed\//)[1].split('"')[0]; }
                else { youtube_id = value.split(/v\/|v=|youtu\.be\//)[1].split(/[?&]/)[0]; }
                value = "http://www.youtube.com/v/"+youtube_id;
                var htmlInput = "<object width=\"640\" height=\"390\"><param name=\"movie\" value=\""+value+"\"></param><param name=\"allowScriptAccess\" value=\"always\"></param><embed src=\""+value+"\" type=\"application/x-shockwave-flash\" allowscriptaccess=\"always\" width=\"640\" height=\"390\"></embed></object>";
                $(this).after("<p>"+htmlInput+"</p>");
            }


        $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: url,

            success: function(result) {
               console.log(result);

              for(var i=0;i<result.data.length;i++)
              {
                $("#tablevidgalleryid").append("<tr><td><a href='"+result.data[i].vidgalleryUrl+"'>"+value+"</a></td></tr>");

              }                                                                                                                             
             $('#tablevidgalleryid').DataTable();

            }
          }); 
}
```

When i was changed manually of watch to embed in link(db), it show has page can't load in browser result.data[i].vidgalleryUrl - a model class variable from entity class. Can someone please point me to a right direction.

Comment: Can you please attached proper Error logs / Consol output that you are getting?

Comment: @Ajinkya  :) hello bro, I have list  of  YouTube URL links in MySQL(DB),I want to get list of Videos to load and run(play)  in html page dynamically.